# Unlock emulator screen using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm developing my first android application and I was setting up the CI server. My espresso tests run fine on my machine but travis errors out with the following

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not be requesting layout for over 10 seconds.

It seems that I need to unlock the emulator screen before I run the tests. To do so I have to add a manifest to `src/debug` with the required permissions and then unlock the screen with:

```
KeyguardManager mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock(name);
mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

The thing is I don't want to litter my activities with the above code wrapped in if blocks. Is there a way to unlock the screen from the espresso test itself?

My espresso test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class EspressoSetupTest {

    @Rule
    public final ActivityTestRule<WelcomeActivity> activity =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(WelcomeActivity.class, true, true);

    @Test
    public void launchTest() {
        onView(withId(R.id.welcome_textView_hello))
                .perform(click())
                .check(matches(withText("RetroLambda is working")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `setUp()` method in your Espresso Test like:

```
@UiThreadTest
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   final Activity activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
    mActivityRule.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          KeyguardManager mKG = (KeyguardManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
          KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock mLock = mKG.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
          mLock.disableKeyguard();

        //turn the screen on
         activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
          }
      });
}
```

**src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have espresso setup differently. I don't have access to the context, and what should the name variable hold?

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it more clear. You can use the activity to get the system service. The name variable is just a tag, you can use the static KEYGUARD_SERVICE string for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks! My espresso test class isn't really subclassing anything though. I'm getting an instance of the activity using ActivityTestRule.getActivity() and putting your code into a @Before setUp() method but that didn't work.

Comment: I am using this in my own espresso tests (but on external devices). You can try to wrap the keyguard parts in `mActivityRule.runOnUiThread()`.